# What is the best way to improve your questions to relieve a ban?

Tags: discussion

I asked 2 questions on my account that were received poorly because I didn't document the problem and steps to reproduce it effectively. One was a question while I was a student and really didn't make any sense, the other is a more recent one that dealt with a very specific problem in flutter/dart.

I was given a ban on asking questions until I'm able to provide the community with quality content.

I took a look at the help document provided by SO as well as looked up some more resources on META.

I was told to go back through my questions and update them to provide a better question in order to get my privileges restored.

I went back and updated my question which had 3 downvotes explaining that I found a fix and it was mainly due to a dependency that was updated. My other questions have either 0 votes or +1 so I'm not sure what more I can do to better the questions on my account.

Could this possibly be because I was asking a large amount of questions that received few upvotes?

How can I be a better SO user so I can overturn this ban and start asking again?

Do answers factor into the question asking ban?

Comment: That does clear up the "does answering questions factor.." portion. I'm just not really sure what more I can edit to improve my questions, and even when I do edit them there is a chance that it might not be viewed further. So I guess I'll wait my 6 months to ask a really good question and see where that gets me. I do have one question that seems like a lot of people viewed it so I might try to edit that one to better it.

Comment: Please note that the Question/Answer format requires the Question part to only contain the question. If you find a solution you can post an Answer to your own Question. Apart from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you may want to read [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Amxela - the fact your question was closed against the FAQ does not mean you won't get responses - just that there will be no answers to reduce information fragmentation and point others with the same problem to the guideline we more or less accept unanimously.

Comment: It takes more than 2 bad questions to be question banned.  Given your question, I can almost guarantee you that, there are more than 2 deleted questions connected to your account.  Were you not presented a notification, that you had reached the question ban threshold, when you asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907674/firebase-messaging-7-0-0-to-9-0-1-conversion) question?  If you are unable to significantly improve your deleted questions, you will simply have to wait 6 months, before asking your next question.  Make sure that question is extremely high quality.

Comment: @SecurityHound literally no deleted questions on my account.

Comment: @Amxela - There are none listed for you.  However, a moderator can provide you the deleted questions, that are no longer considered "recently deleted"

Comment: Just as a note: users with 10k reputation can use the following search query to view all their deleted questions: [`user:me deleted:yes is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aquestion). Users with less than 10k reputation might be able to find them via their reputation history with the procedure [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).